# How to join with a column having comma separated values

Tags: sql, many-to-one, multivalue

I have written a query that joins multiple table and gets the result in the below format.

16-Jan-14  16-Jan-14  4 *9860,9846,9861,11040,11038,11043* 100

The comma separated values is a single column. Now I want to map this csv in the column to their respective names in another table.The result will look like:

16-Jan-14  16-Jan-14  4 *name1,name22,name16,name34,name78,name56* 100

Is there anyway this can be done in the same query which given me my original result.

Appreciate the help.

Regards

Comment: A join? It'd be a lot easier to answer with a schema and an the query you've already got...

Comment: In addition please update your title - it gives a reader no clue what your question is about

Comment: @Liath to describe the schema, the csv values mentioned are rule ids from a table VARIATION having a column rule_id among other columns and there is another table RULE(ID,DESCRIPTION) which has name and id of each rule.The example posted just shows what rules are modified on 16th Jan and it shows the rule ids only. I have to match these values with the rule table to get the corresponding names.But I am not having any idea how to join the csv values with the rule table.

Comment: Sounds like a join will do the job - please can you edit your question to include your original query. We need the table and column names